# Accessing a function inside HOC

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I just want to access componentDidMount in test file, how can I write a test case so that I can access componentDidMount? I just want to print hi in the console.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export const MyComponent = (functionName, secondFunctionName) => (
    WrappedComponent,
) => {
    class WithWrapped extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.getEmployees = props.getEmployees;
            this.clearEmployees = props.clearEmployees;
            this.state = { user: 'test', loading: true };
            this.refreshEmp = this.refreshEmp.bind(this);
        }

        componentDidMount() {
           console.log('Hi')
        }

        UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextContext) {
           
        }

       
        render() {
 
        }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return {
           
        };
    };

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    });

    return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WithWrapped);
};
```

Comment: Why do you want to access `componentDidMount`? You just need to mount the component. Then the `componentDidMount` will execute.

Comment: What are you trying to test?